# How to parse specific links from google search

Tags: html, python-3.x, html-parsing

I'm writing a program that open automatically some browsers tabs with the results from google search. Google always displays shopping results first, then maps results and then links to other websites. I would like to fetch only the links to other websites, excluding maps links and shopping results.

I used the developer tool to check those links and they all seems part of a  element inside a  element.
I tried to get those elements using the select() method with CSS selectors, but I can't get those specific classes.
I already tried the solutions in other answers to similar questions here but with no success.
I tried, then, using regex to filter all the links getting only links that start with "http://" as follow:

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

# I'm using the word 'skateboard' to test

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=skateboard')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html.parser')
for links in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("http://")}):
    print(links.get('href'))
```

but this only returns links related with google maps. Would be very useful if you guys have any idea how to get only those specific elements mentioned before. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: The elements mentioned in the question are links inside element <cite class="iUh30"> inside a <div class="TbwUpd">

Answer (score 0):

problem solved using soup.find_all("tagName", class_="className")